# Is there a way to call a javascript file from the assets folder, to a snippet on Shopify?

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

I have created the code for a finance calculator using a mixture of HTML and Javascript. I had originally created it all in the same liquid file; but now I want to call the Javascript file into the snippet. This was because the Javascript was previously showing in the "Inspect Element: Elements" tab.

I had tried adding a piece of liquid code at the top of the snippet, however it has proved unsuccessful.

```
{{ 'finance-calculator.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
```

When I removed the Javascript from the liquid file, I tried using the liquid code above, however it had broke the calculator and stopped it from making calculations.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the below code in your liquid page - 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ 'finance-calculator.js' | asset_url }}"></script>`

Comment: Hi Kailash, the suggested code you have submitted is not showing up.

Comment: The code you have shown me is not pulling the file through onto the snippet. Thank you in the meantime though!